# Is it necessary to store Key and IVs in some DB while encryption?

Tags: security, encryption

I am using Rijndael Managed class for encrypting some data through my code. I am also generating Key and IV for the same using a fixed password and salt by Rfc2898DeriveBytes class.
But I am not storing these(key,IV, password, Salt) explicitly in DB, instead, I generate them in code onetime , store them in session variables and use them for encryption and decyption while the application is running. So, everything is in my compiled dll. Is that practice safe? I do not want to defeat the sole purpose of encryption.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a good key management practice, but neither is storing them in your application's database.

Ideally, keys should be stored in a hardware security module where they can't be extracted. However, since that is not generally an option for most applications, on Windows (which I'm assuming is you're using, given that this is a .NET app) you have DPAPI which you can use to store the keys, or for the simplest option you could use an encrypted config section to protect them.

As an aside, I'd probably reconsider the use of the password and KDF.  When you have an application that doesn't require a user to remember and type in the password such as a web application that is using the key independently of the users, it's generally a better practice to simply generate a strong random key, and store that directly rather than a password and salt, and have to derive the key.

Comment: Well, I actually used pswd and salt on purpose to derive the key in code because I did not want to store any of them anywhere. What are the possible ways a "derived key " could be extracted from a dll ? I know pswrd and salt should be protected for that purpose.

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena It's six of one, a half dozen of the other.  With the password and salt, anyone else can derive the key as easily as you can.  The dll is not the appropriate place for any of it, because this means that you now have sensitive data that you have to store in source control, share across environments, and generally manage and use in unsafe  ways.

Comment: thanks , Was looking forward to Obfuscation, I guess that will be better in case I still go ahead with deriving key in the code.